# Mxnet Amalgamation compilation issue

Tags: android, mxnet

Has anyone tried Mxnet amalgamation for android recently. I am getting stuck at the below issue. Have tried setting jni path etc, but to no avail

```
python ./amalgamation.py mxnet_predict0.d mxnet_predict0.cc mxnet_predict-all.cc 0 
Not processed: mxnet_predict0.o:
g++ -std=c++11 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wall -I/home/ubuntu/newopenblas -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1 -O3 -fPIC -o jni_libmxnet_predict.o -c jni/predictor.cc
jni/predictor.cc:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

add -I/NDK_HOME/sysroot/usr/include to makefile

edit the Makefile of mxnet/amalgamation/

add:
export NDK_ROOT=your/Android/ndk/root/path

edit:
CFLAGS += -I${OPENBLAS_ROOT} -I${OPENBLAS_ROOT}/include -**I${NDK_ROOT}/sysroot/usr/include**